nginx comparing length of variables in config files
I need to compare the length of variables, for example,
if ( strlen($query_string) < 16 ) {
      return 301;
}

I could find nginx documentation on string and other comparison but could not find about the length of the content. Any help will be appreciated.

Nginx regular expressions should support the repetition quantifier ({min,max}).
You will need to enclose it in quotes because of the braces.
For example:
if ( $query_string ~ "^.{,15}$" ) {
    return 301;
}

